# Are there any hooks for the event when an user navigates the verification URL?

Tags: 7, hooks, users

I'm looking for a way to modify an event (from my own module) when an user navigates to the account activation URL that they get in their mails. Are there any such hooks ready for me to use?

Also I would potentially need the `$account-> mail` variable if it's passed as an argument by any chance.

I've used this but it doesn't work as intended -

```
function my_module_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id)
{
    // Trigger when at password reset form
    if ($form_id == 'user_pass_reset') {}
}
```

But the problem is I cannot seem to access the `$account` variable that way. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured it out.

```
function my_module_lists_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id)
{
    // Trigger when at password reset form
    if ($form_id == 'user_pass_reset')
    {
        // If $account has not been defined, define it from $user
        if (empty($account)) 
        {
            // Loads the user using the user id argument
            $account = user_load($form_state['build_info']['args'][0]);
        }

        // Log something
        watchdog('DEBUG MESSAGE:', 'We are there, user : ('.$account->mail.')!');
    }
}
```

If anybody has a better method, please do share.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you are using the [User Verification](https://www.drupal.org/project/user_verify) module. If yes, then you can try the hook they provide

```
hook_user_verify_verified
```

Hope this helps...